# Performing regression while dividing sample

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

Let's take data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
df = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/wdbc.data', header=None)
```

And consider code following :

```
#Defining X,y - independent variable and dependent variables
X=df.drop(df.columns[[1]], axis=1)
y = (df[1] == 'B').astype(int)
clf=LogisticRegression(solver="lbfgs")
        

kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)

for train, validation in kfold.split(X, y):
            # Fit the model
            clf.fit(X[train], y[train])
```

And the following error occurs :

[image]

Do you have any idea why it occurs ? I think I did really not complicated things, so I'm not sure what exactly I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X is a DataFrame so you need to use `.iloc` to select the indices:

```
for train_index, validation_index in kfold.split(X, y):
    # Fit the model
    X_train = X.iloc[train_index]
    y_train = y[train_index]
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```